# Specific UITableView cells redirect to safari and don't push to new view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a working UITableView implemented inside a UIVIewController and it's all fine. In my tableView, i already created 2 types of custom cell, cell1 contains the data i need , and cell2 contains a simple uiimageview. cell2 is present only on indexpath.row ==3 and index path.row == 7. The UITableView loads correctly and everything is just fine.
Inside my image view, i load a static image , from a url , with the possibility of redirecting when the user clicks that cell. It is loaded like this :

```
  imageAdName1 = [adImageArray objectAtIndex:1];


        [cell2.imagView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageAdName1]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];


      //  imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                        action:@selector(imageViewTapped2:)];
```

Note that i added a tapGestrure on it so when the user clicks it will redirect him, like this :

```
- (void)imageViewTapped2:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[adURLRedirectionArray objectAtIndex:1]]];
}
```

While testing, if i click on those 2 specific cells , the one row index 3 and 7 , i get a successful redirection, and takes me out to safari as it should, but when i come back to the app, i find that it pushed to the data view controller, as if it was a normal cell. I want when the user clicks on those specific cells, he get only redirected without pushing to the next view controller.

 how can i do this ? Many thanks for your help

Comment: If you are doing it from code, modify your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method so you push a view controller only when certain rows are tapped. If you are using Interface Builder and segues, add your logic to `prepareForSegue:sender:`.

Comment: @Adam can you please give me an example regarding tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath ? i tried many methods but i think i'm doing something wrong..can you please provide an example? thank you

Comment: @Adam thank you you gave a head's up on what was going on with me ! post ur comment as an answer so i can accept it … thank u

Comment: What about adding a transparent button on top of image view instead of adding tap gesture? Then you can have both imageViewTapped2: and tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: depending on where you tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing it from code, modify your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method so you push a view controller only when certain rows are tapped. If you are using Interface Builder and segues, add your logic to `prepareForSegue:sender:`.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 7) {
      // Redirect to browser (or do nothing if you want to use the tap gesture)
    } else {
      // Push view controller
    }
}
```